# Grouping last record in SQL

Tags: sql, grouping

```
SELECT BLMASKODU
    ,BLKODU
FROM CARI_NOTLAR
WHERE BLMASKODU = '2'
```

The results are shown below

```
+===========+========+
| blmaskodu | blkodu |
+===========+========+
|         2 |    171 |
+-----------+--------+
|         2 |    515 |
+-----------+--------+
|         2 |    618 |
+-----------+--------+
|         2 |    675 |
+-----------+--------+
```

I would like to take latest blkodu for each blmaskodu. There are more than 1000 blmaskodu and keep increasing.

Comment: What do you mean by latest? do you have some date field that you can sort by?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT BLMASKODU
    ,MAX(BLKODU) AS BLKODU
FROM CARI_NOTLAR
WHERE BLMASKODU = '2'
GROUP BY BLMASKODU
```

I am using [MAX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql) to retrieve the maximum value in the expression, and [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) to perform an aggregation on the group of `BLMASKODU`'s.

Result if there were a few `BLMASKODU` IDs in the database:
[image]

Setup for my testing:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CARI_NOTLAR](
    [blmaskodu] INT,
    [blkodu] INT,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[CARI_NOTLAR]
SELECT '2','171' UNION ALL
SELECT '2','515' UNION ALL
SELECT '2','618' UNION ALL
SELECT '2','675' UNION ALL
SELECT '5','333' UNION ALL
SELECT '5','432' UNION ALL
SELECT '5','777' UNION ALL
SELECT '5','123' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','3343' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','22' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','111' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','5233'
GO

SELECT BLMASKODU
    ,MAX(BLKODU) AS BLKODU
FROM CARI_NOTLAR
--WHERE BLMASKODU = '2'
GROUP BY BLMASKODU
```

Try it here: [SQL Example](http://rextester.com/ZUPXU2055)